Measurable functions from logical formulas
Let $A(X, Y)$ be an arithmetical formula with (only) second-order variables $X, Y\subset \mathbb{N}$.
Assuming $(\forall X\subset \mathbb{N})(\exists Y\subset\mathbb{N})A(X, Y)$, there is a choice function $Z$ such that $(\forall X\subset \mathbb{N})A(X, Z(X))$.
Is there always a measurable such $Z$?

Probably you know this, but the keyword is: uniformization. You are asking whether every arithmetic subset of the plane with all slices nonempty is uniformized by a measurable function. There are many theorems in descriptive set theory about the complexity of uniformizing functions in terms of the complexity of the set in the plane.

It seems to me that the result mentioned in this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/199598/1946 would provide an arithmetic relation $A(x,y)$ with no hyperarithmetic selector. Namely, $A(x,y)$ holds when $y$ is a branch through the tree $T_x$.

Jankov/von Neumman comes close but the $\sigma$-algebra involved is too big as far as the desired conclusion goes; see also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/176672/uniformization-measurable-selection-theorems. Of course, assuming large cardinals we get a positive answer (e.g. projective uniformization + all projective sets are measurable for galactic overkill).

On the other hand, here is a possibly-relevant negative result.

Noah's latter example is the same argument (and same user, but different post) as in my link above.

@JoelDavidHamkins Whoops, didn't notice that!

I think the following is a potential counterexample: let $A(X,Y)\equiv$ "Either $X\not\ge_T0'$ and $Y=\emptyset$ or $X\ge_T\emptyset'$ and $Y'=X$." This is arithmetic (since everything can be expressed in terms of initial segments of $X$ and $Y$), and a selector would have to provide "uniform jump inversion" above $0'$. There are various results saying (at least under a further assumption of degree-invariance) that no such function can be tame in one sense or other; however, I don't offhand know whether nonmeasurability specifically is known to be implied by this (so this is just a comment).

You expect an analytic selection, but in general not a Borel selection.

@NoahSchweber Could you explain why Jankov-von Neumann is not enough? I thought the $\sigma$-algebra generated by analytic sets was contained in the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra?

@n901 I interpreted "measurable" as "Borel-measurable." It depends on exactly what the OP means.
